# Accessing first node of linkedlist in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

so I'm trying to access the first node of a linkedlist using the address and it doesn't seem to be making a ton of sense to me. The struct that the linkedlist is stored is defined as

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct ListNode *next;
 * };
 */
```

I have initialized a linkedlist with

```
struct ListNode* l3;
```

And each time I call l3->next, I precede it with

```
 l3->next = (void *) malloc(size * sizeof(struct ListNode));
```

I have stored the address of the first node of the linked list with:

```
int* first;
first = (int *) l3; //noting that (void *) is also a valid cast
```

And I do get a valid address print out of 0x1235270. I'm trying to access the val of that first node using

```
printf("%d\n", first->val);
```

And it gives me the:

```
Line 29: request for member 'val' in something not a structure or union
```

error. Yet when I return first in leetcode (as I'm trying to do a question there), it does detect it as a linkedlist (shows a linkedlist in the output). I was wondering what I'm doing wrong, and how I actually access the values of the first node.

Comment: Note that `struct ListNode* l3;` doesn't *initialize* `l3` (unless it's a global variable). Your assignment to `l3->next` is also suspect (dereferencing either an uninitialized or a null pointer), as well as it (by itself) doesn't create a linked list.

Comment: As for your error, `first` isn't a pointer to the `ListNode` structure, it's a pointer to an `int`. The fact that you had to cast `l3` for the assignment should be a sign that you did something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry, it was a very dumb mistake. Once I cast the pointer from int * to struct node *, it worked.